# Callback after list leave animation and DOM update - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, transitionend

To do something after the DOM has been updated by Vue, you use the `$nextTick` binding.

To do something after a css transition has completed, you can use `transitionend` event.

I have a dynamic list in which things are added and removed by user actions. When removed, there is a CSS animation and then I need to check the state of the DOM immediately after the element is gone.

I was thinking that the `$nextTick` after the `transitionend` would be the state of the DOM immediately after the list item is removed, but it is not.

I need to do something after the transition has ended **and** the element from a list has been removed from the DOM.

Right now I have:

```
<transition-group class="message-bus" tag="ul" name="message-bus">
    <li v-for="message in messages" v-bind:key="message.id" :ref="message.id">
        <div>{{message.text}}</div>
        <a class="dismiss-message" @click="dismissMessage(message)">&times;</a>
    </li>
</transition-group>

dismissMessage(message){
    const vm = this;

    this.$refs[message.id][0].addEventListener("transitionend", function(){
        vm.$nextTick(function(){
            //This is called, but appears to be called before the element is actually removed from the DOM
            //I need to query the DOM immediately after this element is removed 
        });
    });

    this.messages.splice(this.messages.indexOf(message), 1);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the mounted function, I have added a `MutationObserver` that appears to be working as needed. I'll put this here as an answer as it *does technically work* and may be helpful to others, but I'm still interested in a better answer if Vue has something built in for this.

```
mounted(){
    const vm = this;
    const listItemRemoved = new MutationObserver(function(e){
        if (e[0].removedNodes.length){
            console.log("Removed");
        }
    });
    listItemRemoved.observe(this.$el, {childList: true});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a [custom directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html). Perform the actions you need inside the `unbind` hook ..

```
created() {
    this.vm = this
},
directives: {
  foo: {
    unbind(el, binding) {
      // Here you can perform the actions you need.
      // You can access the Vue instance using binding.value (eg: binding.value.$el)
    }
  }
},
```

And in your template ..

```
<transition-group class="message-bus" tag="ul" name="message-bus">
    <li v-for="message in messages" v-bind:key="message.id" :ref="message.id" v-foo="vm">
        <div>{{message.text}}</div>
        <a class="dismiss-message" @click="dismissMessage(message)">&times;</a>
    </li>
</transition-group>
```